# How to access to external scripts loaded by javascript via script element

Tags: javascript, external

I want to create my own asset loader. To load external scripts, I used following javascript

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.onload = function() {
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    callback();
  };
  script.src = src;
}
```

But I think this isn't the most elegant solution. This code snippet would make my HTML code ugly since it appends code to the head - for all of my dependencies.

So my question: is it possible to access to my external loaded code without using following line

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Am I able to executes my script with pure js like

```
script.execute();
```

Or even better, is there a way to access to the data stored in my external js file? Like variable "bar", for example?

```
var foo = script.get("bar")
```

Could I even execute a function of the external file?

```
script.function(params)
```

It would be great to hear of your ideas and experiences!
Darth Moon

Edit: I forgot to exclude ajax. I know I could load code via ajax and executes it via eval(), but that won't be a good idea if you're testing code local since you need a Server (like an XAMPP Apache) to send ajax request to your local files.

Comment: What about `require.js`?

Comment: I don't know it. But won't it also adds script tags under the hood?

Comment: I looked into the require.js file. Is it true that they just evaluate the code they loaded? Isn't that insecure? I always hears "Eval is evil", so what's with require.js? And how do they exactly access to the code they loaded?

Comment: You are going to be evaluating the code one way or another. The "eval is evil" idiom comes from evaluating *user generated* input as code. If you are importing a malicious script, it's not going to end well regardless.

Comment: And the typical syntax is something like `var importedModule = require('importPath.js')`. What exists in `importedModule` can be controlled by `module.exports`.

Comment: Good comment. And how do they access to the code at all?

Comment: For web code? Probably an AJAX request to the CDN. For local code? Probably through `fs`. It depends on the execution environment and the source.

Comment: And that's my problem...

Comment: You don't need to know the specifics for how it resolves paths to files; you can use `require('./relativePath.js')` for both local and externally hosted files.

Comment: Isn't require() node js? Or do you mean require.js? It's great to hear that require.js is what I need, but first my asset loader won't only load javascripts, and second I think more than 2000 lines of code ar a bit too much for only including external scripts. I want to know __how__ require.js works under the hood, not, whether it works at all.

Comment: `require.js`, maybe [reading this](https://requirejs.org/docs/why.html) will give you some ideas.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like so as below.

Internal script:

```
function appendScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement(‘script’);
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

External script:

```
function loadedScript() {
   // run something
}

loadedScript()
```

The external code will just run loadedScript() once the file is loaded.

Comment: It seems like the point of the question is to avoid `document.head.appendChild` entirely.

Comment: Not a bad idea. So I also could execute loadedScript()  in other js files. Nice :) But, as @JaredGoguen says, I want to avoid document.head.appendChild entirely. To prevent ugly code. And to make it difficult to see my js code in the web console :)

Comment: In that case, would recommend on having it in a function rather than a script file. Such as calling function A and function A will run function B and function C, then those will do the relevant actions needed tho.

Comment: Bad if I want to access to js code I didn't write at all.

Comment: Well, maybe you could try https://requirejs.org to require the specific module and run the code acted as the var to be the module